# How do I call a method on a different activity?

Tags: android, kotlin

Im working on an android app which uses notifications frequently.

I chose to set the alarms via setting activity rather then Main Activity but I couldn't manage to find out how to cancel the Alarm Manager via the settingActivity immediately after pressing the switch.

I only found out how to cancel the notifications on the MainActivity, which stops them only after closing and opening the app.

what is the preferred way to do it?

from SettingActivity.kt:

```
class NotificationPreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_notification)
        setHasOptionsMenu(false)

        var switchPref: Preference = findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_notifications_switch_key))

        switchPref.onPreferenceChangeListener = OnPreferenceChangeListener { preference, isChecked ->
            var toast: Toast = if (isChecked as Boolean) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "switch is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "notifications is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)

            }
            toast.show()
            true
        }
    }
```

cancel method from MainActivity:

```
fun cancelAlarm() {
    alarmMgr = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent1 = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    alarmMgr!!.cancel(alarmIntent)
}
```

Comment: You should be able to use a BroadcastReceiver for this

Answer (score 0):

As said by a commenter, just use BroadcastReceiver

NotificationPreferenceFragment.java

```
class NotificationPreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment() {

    val broadcaster: LocalBroadcastManager? = null;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        broadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
    }

    // Inside your onPreferenceChangeListener, depends on when you want to call it, either ON or OFF
    Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR_DATA_STRING");
    intent.putExtra(ANY_EXTRAS_STRING, DATA_ITSELF);
    broadcaster.sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;




    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(MYReceiver,
                IntentFilter("YOUR_DATA_STRING")
        )
    }

    private val MYReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            if (intent.extras != null) {
                // get any extras if neccessary
                // intent.extras!!.getString("ANY_EXTRAS_STRING")
                cancelAlarm()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(MYReceiver)
    }
```